# What is the difference between visibility:collapse and display:none? Which one is the preferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Recently I've spent a few minutes tracking down a bug in my code investigating why JQuery's .show() does not show one of my originally invisible element. As it turned out, JQuery .show() and hide() switch the `display:none` and my element was hidden by `visibility:collapse`.

OK, bug is solved, however I am wondering is there any difference between `display:none` and `visibility:collapse`?. (I do understand what is the difference between `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:collapse`).

Also I am wondering if there is no difference which is the preferred?

Comment: see the definition in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Comment: For table rows, columns, column groups, and row groups the row(s) or column(s) are hidden and the space they would have occupied is removed (as if display: none were applied to the column/row of the table). However, the size of other rows and columns is still calculated as though the cells in the collapsed row(s) or column(s) are present. This was designed for fast removal of a row/column from a table without having to recalculate widths and heights for every portion of the table.

Comment: @ShijuKBabu: you are right. Sorry for the dupe, I definitely searched both google, both SO, with pretty selective keywords like difference display none, collapse and there was no result...

Comment: If I type `difference display none, collapse` into google, the other question is the first result. Oh, and the second result is [a similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/133051/1016716) from 2008.

Comment: @MrLister: You are right, my bad, I do not understand how could I missed it...